Suppose two sets $X,Y$ are such that $|X| < |Y|$ and $X$ is infinite. Prove that $Y$ must also be an infinite set.
Suppose two sets $X,Y$ are such that $|X| < |Y|$ and $X$ is infinite. Prove that $Y$ must also be an infinite set.
Since $X$ has a cardinality strictly lesser than that of $Y$, $\exists$ $f : X \to Y$ such that $f$ is injective. Assume on the contrary that $Y$ is finite.
$\displaystyle \bigcup_{y \in Y} f^{-1}(y) \in X \implies |Y| \stackrel{injectivity}{=} \left|\displaystyle \bigcup_{y \in Y} f^{-1}(y)\right| \leq |X|$ is a contradiction.
This doesn't seem incorrect but I think this is missing certain details. For instance, there might axioms (like AOC) or others that I may have been using without mentioning it. I need help in writing a completely rigorous proof.

It might be helpful to say your definition of infinite.

Actually, since $f$ in injective, it results that $;|Y|\geqslant\left|\bigcup\limits_{y\in Y}f^{-1}(y)\right|.;$ Moreover, if $Y$ is a finite set and $f$ is injective but not surjective, then $;|Y|>\left|\bigcup\limits_{y\in Y}f^{-1}(y)\right|.;$

Before writing a completely rigorous proof, we need make rigorous definitions. Let us say a set $A$ is finite if there is a bijection between $A$ and $\{1, \dots, n\} := \{k\in \mathbb{N} | 1 \leq k \leq n\}$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ (I am using $\mathbb{N} = \{0, 1, 2, \dots\}$. Note that $n$ can be $0$, in which case $\{k\in \mathbb{N} | 1 \leq k \leq n\}$ is empty), and we say $A$ is infinite if it is not finite.
Now, let $f : X \to Y$ be an injection. To prove that $X$ is infinite implies $Y$ is infinite, we can equivalently prove the contrapositive, which is that $Y$ is finite implies $X$ is finite (in fact, this is a constructively stronger statement using our definitions).
The statement that $Y$ is finite implies $X$ is finite is actually quite obvious if we adopt an alternative characterization of finite set. Let us say a set $A$ is subfinite if there exists an injection from $A$ to $\{1, \dots, n\}$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$. It is clear that if $Y$ is subfinite, then $X$ is subfinite by composition of injections.
So the question reduces to showing that subfiniteness is indeed equivalent to finiteness. That finiteness implies subfiniteness is obvious. We will prove the other direction. Assume that $A$ is subfinite, hence there exists injection $i : A \to \{1, \dots, n\}$, we wish to show that $A$ is finite. Define $g : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ by recursion
$$
g(0) = 0
\quad
\text{and}
\quad
g(n) = g(n - 1) + \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } n \in i(A), \\
0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
The idea is that $g(n)$ is the number of $a \in A$ such that $i(a) \leq n$.
Note that $g$ is bounded by $n$, so there exists a maximum $m := \max g(\mathbb{N})$. Also, note that $g \circ i(a)$ can never be $0$ for any $a \in A$, so we can restrict $g \circ i$ to a function $g \circ i : A \to \{1, \dots, m\}$. The fact that this function is injective can be attributed to the non-decreasing nature of $g$, and that it is surjective is due to the well-ordering nature of $\mathbb{N}$ (for all $k \in \{1, \dots, m\}$, $k = g(s)$ where $s = \min\{s'\in \mathbb{N} | g(s') \geq k\}$ which satisfies $s \in i(A)$).

To prove the statement in the simplest way, we use the method of contraposition. This means it suffices to show that if $Y$ is finite and there exists an injection function from $X$ to $Y$, then $X$ is finite.
First, recall that the statement "$Y$ is finite" implies the existence of a bijection function from $Y$ to some natural number $n$. Given that there is an injection function from $X$ to $Y$, we can deduce that there exists an injection function from $X$ to $n$. This, in turn, implies that $X$ is finite, which is the desired result.
